# Dynamic Linq Order By Parent and Child Collection

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

I'm using System.Linq.Dynamic.

Given this parent - child (collection) model below, is it possible use OrderBy Client based on createdDate property passing the Id of the specific Address to sort with? Alternatively, Client properties can be used for the main sort as well. It also has to be sorted by Last and First Name.

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public string Type {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime modifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a generic way to do all the scenarios?

1. OrderBy(Client.Addresses.Where("Id = @0", idValue).CreatedDate + " ASC , LastName DESC, FirstName DESC")
2. OrderBy("Type DESC, LastName DESC, FirstName DESC")

Comment: Try something like `.OrderBy(Client.Addresses.First("Id = @0", idValue).CreatedDate).ThenBy(LastName).ThenBy(FirstName")`

Comment: @Emanuele First only accepts 1 argument and I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

When using [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core), you should be able to use:

```
.OrderBy("Type DESC, LastName DESC, FirstName DESC")
```

See also : https://dynamic-linq.net/basic-simple-query#ordering-results

Comment: thanks, I've verified scenario 2 works. Would you know if scenario 1 is also supported by dynamic linq?